# Automatic footer resizing CSS

Tags: css, resize, footer

I have a footer that contains 2 rows of 3 links - when the browser window is resized and goes too small, the links get cut off. Is there any way to keep the footer full size while the rest of the window gets resized?

```
.footer { position: fixed; top: 90%; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
      background: #ffffff; border: solid black; border-width: 2px 0 0 0; }
```

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? I'm guessing you're saying that content in the footer is being cropped at the bottom because the footer height isn't long enough to show it all?  I think that will be an inherent problem with the method you're using.  Perhaps if you explain what you're trying to do, alternative solutions can be proposed?  Off the top of my head, you could use media queries to shrink the font-size of the footer, as the page shrinks, to try to get it to fit.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/utb6z/

Sounds like you're right about the inherent problem. I'm trying to divide a page into 4 different coloured quadrants, using divs. Then adding a footer in also.

Answer (score 0):

set a "min-width" for your div

```
.footer { 
    position: fixed; 
    top: 90%; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    background: #fff; 
    border-top: 2px solid #000;

    min-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: It's not so much the width i'm concerned about, it's the height. When the window is say half height, the footer does not adjust.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `min-height` to the footer, as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4tMjX/):

```
.footer { 
    position: fixed; 
    height: 10%;
    min-height: 40px;
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    background: #fff; 
    border-top: 2px solid black; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is fixing the footer to the bottom of the page an option? just delete the `top: 90%;` and the footer will retain it's height even when the window is half-sized

```
.footer { 
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0;
    background: #fff; 
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
}
```

PS I forked your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6s5eN/